# How to completely remove an empty array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have searched and searched and cannot find an answer to this, so please accept my apologies if I am being foolish.

I am building an application in node.js that uses JSON files as project configs. I am using the 'fs' module to read the JSON file, which I then parse into a Javascript object. I then amend details within the object before using JSON.stringify to write the data back to the file.

My problem is that I need to delete an array, not just empty it, in order to show the data correctly on my interface:

```
"floors": [
    {
        "floorName": "Grd Floor",
        "floorNotes": "",
        "floorPlan": "Buckley_Grd.jpg",
        "floorWidth": "57.392",
        "floorHeight": "20.776",
        "runs": [
            [],  *<----I cannot delete these*
            []   *<----only empty them*
            [
                {
                    "xCoOrd": "37.88235294117647",
                    "yCoOrd": "59.307359307359306",
                    "drawingType": "node"
                },
                {
                    "xCoOrd": "37.88235294117647",
                    "yCoOrd": "59.307359307359306",
                    "drawingType": "node"
                },
                {
                    "xCoOrd": "48.549019607843135",
                    "yCoOrd": "50",
                    "drawingType": "node"
                }
            ]   *<----I don't want to delete the elements in this array*
        ]
    }
```

I have tried:

```
.splice(0);
.filter(Boolean);
delete
```

Everywhere I have looked people seem surprised that one would want to delete an unused array from memory, which is what I beleive I am trying to do. Perhaps there is a way to stringify the object that ignores these empty arrays? Or perhaps I am doing this completely the wrong way?

Many thanks in advance for any advice offered.

EDIT: I should have made clearer that I don't necessarily want to delete all of the elemnets in the array so redeclaring floors.runs =[] unfortunately will not help me.

I have tried:

```
delete floors[floorID].runs[runID];
```

This replaces the array with null which gets written to the file and ruins my reading of the JSON.

Comment: How did you try `delete`?

Comment: have you tried to set "runs" to `null` ?

Comment: Define "delete an array". Clarify what exactly you tried, and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: To joke around,  myarray="deleted".... What was an array is now something else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want remove ALL values from `runs` array you simply do this:

```
floors[i].runs = null
```

If you want remove only the empties

```
var filled = [];
obj.floors[i].runs.forEach(function(value, i, array) {
    if (value.length != 0) filled.push(value);
});

obj.floors[i].runs = filled;
```

Comment: Many thanks; I can see this being a good way of achieving the correct result. Jason's answer below seemed like a good one to me, but I have had problems with it before which I now cannot replicate for some reason, however this definitely works!!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try over-writing the 'runs' property of each object? If you said `floors[0].runs = []` (or `floors[i].runs = []`, if you're looping through), then those two empty arrays would no longer show up in your stringify.

*Editing my answer, to match the OP edits:*

```
floors.forEach(function(floor){
   var newRuns = [];
   floor.runs.forEach(function(run){
       if (run.length > 0){
           newRuns.push(run);
       }
   })
   floor.runs = newRuns;
})
```

After I assign your object from the OP into a variable and run my code on it, then stringify the result, I get this as a return:

```
{"floors":[{"floorName":"Grd Floor","floorNotes":"","floorPlan":"Buckley_Grd.jpg","floorWidth":"57.392","floorHeight":"20.776","runs":[[{"xCoOrd":"37.88235294117647","yCoOrd":"59.307359307359306","drawingType":"node"},{"xCoOrd":"37.88235294117647","yCoOrd":"59.307359307359306","drawingType":"node"},{"xCoOrd":"48.549019607843135","yCoOrd":"50","drawingType":"node"}]]}]}
```

Is that what you're hoping to see? I used this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ubs8mnf/) to produce that result.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. From other comments it appears I have not been clear enough, so I will edit them. I want to delete individual elements within the array, but may need to keep others so to redeclare the array in this way would delete those would it not?

Comment: Yes, my original code would wipe out all references to anything that had been stored in runs. I updated my code to fit the edit you made to the OP. Let me know if it's not what you're looking for, I'll be happy to trying helping further.

Comment: This seems similar to Max' answer below and most appreciated as well! I have different parts of my code to add and delete entire individual elements from a run as well as entire runs and keep coming up against this issue whereby a null value creeps in. Since I am using the JSON to then plot a line onto a background, this stuffs everything up. Your code and Max's below both clear these values out. Many thanks!! (Not sure which one to mark as the answer though - possibly Max' as he answered first)

Comment: Yes, I would have totally understood if you accepted Max's first, we followed the same logic. I appreciate the accept, though -- and good luck with all in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Runs is a property of an object, you can remove items from that array. In your example above floors[0].runs.splice(0,2), should remove both of those arrays I think.

Comment: Many thanks. I have tried this and this seems the best solution, but genuinely I have this intermittent issue whereby it seems to replace the array with a null value when running on my local machine (Mac), but when i run on my Linux server it works perfectly! I am aware how crazy this sounds so if I have tried to upvote your response, but cannot as I am so new!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

## Keeping the same reference

Iterating downwards lets you safely perform operations which decrease the *length* of an *Array* by `1` each time

```
var i, parentArray = obj['floors'][0]['runs'];
for (i = parentArray.length; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (parentArray[i].length === 0) parentArray.splice(i, 1);
}
```

## Making a new reference

Creating a new array without the values you don't want can be achieved using `.filter`

```
obj['floors'][0]['runs'] = obj['floors'][0]['runs'].filter(function (x) {
    return x.length > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an object completely you have to remove the reference from the parent. To do this what you can do is create a new `Array` in which you copy only the references to the non-empty arrays.

I have created this function which should remove all empty arrays. I haven't tested it too much, but this should give you an idea:

```
function clearEmptyArrays(obj) {
   for(var key in obj) {

    var arr = obj[key];

    if(Array.isArray(arr)) {
      // Iterate through all elements and remove empty arrays
      var nonEmptyArr = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        // Recursive call if it's an object inside an array
        if(typeof arr[i] === 'object') clearEmptyArrays(arr);

        // Save all non-empty arrays or objects inside this one
        if((Array.isArray(arr[i]) && arr[i].length > 0) || !Array.isArray(arr[i])) {        
            nonEmptyArr.push(arr[i]);
         }
      }

      obj[key] = nonEmptyArr;
      return;
    }

    // Recursive call if it's an object
    if(typeof arr === 'object') {
        clearEmptyArrays(arr);
    }
  }
}
```

You can call it like this: `clearEmptyArrays(myObj);` and will update the Object in-place.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zeo7dauh/

Comment: Many thanks. I can see this working on your jsfiddle, but for some reason in my code it does not.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Do you get any errors? Probably there is something wrong with the recursivity.